# How to reduce white margins in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have problem with plot output in Shiny. Using standard ggplots I have correct output, means without extra white margines, but when I'm using "ggmap" package (which outputs are also ggplot type) white margines appear

(Just ignore polish words, it's not important)
!Example:
[image: Example image]

Code: ui.R

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(class="row2",
           tags$head(
             tags$style("body {background-color: #94BEE8; height: 600px}")
           ),
           column(
             h3("Filtry"),
             dateInput("date", label=h5("Data"), value = "2014-09-07", min = "2014-09-01", max="2014-09-14"),
             sliderInput("godz", label=h5("Godzina"), min = 0, max = 23, value = 15, animate= TRUE),
             textInput("text1", label=h5("Adres I"), value="Piotrkowska 30, Lodz"),
             textInput("text2", label=h5("Adres II"), value = "Uniwersytecka 5, Lodz"),
             numericInput("r", label=h5("Promień [w km]"), value = 1, min = 0.1, max = 100),
             sliderInput("zoom", label="", min =1, max = 21, value = 13),
             submitButton(text="Wprowadź dane"),
             width = 2),
           column(5,
                  div(plotOutput("mapa", width = "100%")
                      , style = "height: 300px; background-color: #94BEE8;")
           ),
           column(5,
                  htmlOutput("tabela")
           ))
  ))
```

Part of server.R

```
 # Plotting
    g <- p+
        geom_point(data = data, aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE, size = LICZBA.NUMEROW), col = "yellow")+
        geom_point(data= data, aes(x=LONGITUDE, y=LATITUDE, size = (0.625)*LICZBA.NUMEROW), col ="black", alpha = 0.4)+
        geom_point(data=adres1, aes(x=lon, y=lat), size=15, col = "blue", alpha = 0.35)+
        geom_point(data=adres2, aes(x=lon, y=lat), size =15, col ="red", alpha=0.35)+
       xlab("")+ylab("")+ggtitle("TYTUŁ")+
        theme(
          legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.title=element_text(""),
          legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black"),
          legend.background = element_rect(fill="#94BEE8"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#94BEE8", colour = 'red')
          )+scale_colour_discrete(name="LICZBA POŁĄCZEŃ")
  plot(p)
    }, width=500, height=500)
```

Problem 2.
I have problem with adding to ggmap object rectangle or circle with, for example, 2km radius.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
+coord_fixed(ratio = 1.45)
```

It isn't exact anwser but works fine.

The second problem I have solved by application of `geom_polygon()`. I don't know why it wasn't working lately.